# MySQL InnoDB insertion is very slow

Tags: mysql, macos, performance

We use MySQL server 5.1.43 64-bit edition. InnoDB is used as engine.

We have a sql script which we execute every time we build the application.

On ubuntu machine with MySQL server and InnoDB engine it takes about 55 seconds to complete the execution.

If I run the same script on OSX, it takes close to 3 minutes!

Any ideas why OSX is so slow while executing this script?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that your query selects data from the members table. Am I correct?

Comment: No. We are having only insert statements. No select...insert stuff.

Comment: How different are the two machines? Are the speeds of the harddrives the same?
Also, how many rows are you inserting?

Comment: Machine is the same...

Dual boot Linux / Mac. So hardware remains the same in benchmark.

Comment: How do the MySQL configurations differ between the two boot environments? I assume you're comparing the same storage engine (InnoDB) for both?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try starting the server with `my.ini` changed

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

and change back to

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
```

for production usage.

I suspected that the fsync api in osx is slower than linux?

Answer (score 0):

my crystal balls need more information.
its not the same executing a script against a db on the same machine , consider the network overhead. especially if the inserts are data intensive

Comment: We are executing everything on local machine. Network overhead / machine configuration is eliminated. Only difference is the OS and nothing else.